# Analyze error when autorelease called on object returned by class_createInstance

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm adding code provided by a partner to my iOS project that calls `class_createInstance` and then calls `autorelease` before returning, like this:

```
Class functionClass = objc_getClass(functionName);
NSObject* functionObject = class_createInstance(functionClass, 0);
[[functionObject performSelector:@selector(initWithDictionary:) withObject:msg] autorelease];
```

When running Analyze in Xcode 4.0.2, I get the following warning on the last line:

```
Object sent -autorelease too many times
```

**Question 1:**  *How is that object getting sent autorelease too many times?*
My understanding of `class_createInstance` is that I need to release the value it returns.

**Question 2:**  *If the code is correct, how can I avoid the warning from Analyze?*
We have a pretty strict policy to not check in any Analyze warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a decidedly odd pattern and, thus, the analyzer simply isn't aware of it.  Use of `class_createInstance()` is extremely rare.

Two possible solutions off the top of my head:

1. Use the preprocessor markup to tell the analyzer that, yes, in fact, functionObject is a retained reference (I don't have the markup handy -- you'll find it in the release notes or on the llvm.org site or search the system headers).
2. Don't use `class_createInstance()`.  Once you have a reference to the class, just use `+alloc`.  Better yet, rewrite the entire expression as `[[objc_getClass(functionName) alloc] initWithDictionary:msg]` and be done with it.

You should also file a bug via http://bugreporter.apple.com as, though odd, the static analyzer shouldn't barf on that.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I chose to call `alloc` with the class object and that solved the problem.  That's a much better solution than what they were doing before (it's not my code).  I also files a bug with Apple.